# 404 error for servlets in Eclipse/JBoss Dynamic Web Project

Tags: eclipse, servlets, jboss

I have setup a dynamic web project using Servlets and HTML/CSS/JS. While deploying the project, any request sent to the servlets via AJAX, leads to a 404 error every time starting from today. 
Also adding any new servlets has the same effect - 404.

However, the HTML pages are rendered fine with working JS and CSS. (No 404).

Here is the console output on running the project :

```
20:41:17,765 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
20:41:18,304 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
20:41:18,399 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
20:41:20,334 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
20:41:20,335 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
20:41:20,379 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
20:41:20,418 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
20:41:20,456 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
20:41:20,464 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
20:41:20,527 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
20:41:20,611 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
20:41:20,614 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
20:41:20,663 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
20:41:20,672 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
20:41:20,716 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
20:41:20,747 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
20:41:20,945 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
20:41:21,024 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
20:41:21,120 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
20:41:21,143 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
20:41:21,312 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
20:41:21,695 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-4) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080
20:41:22,716 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
20:41:22,720 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/mydb]
20:41:22,904 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999
20:41:22,905 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017100: Listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:4447
20:41:22,921 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /usr/local/share/jboss/standalone/deployments
20:41:22,935 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found VodaBillEAR.ear in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called VodaBillEAR.ear.dodeploy
20:41:22,936 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found Vodafone BillingEAR.ear in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called Vodafone BillingEAR.ear.dodeploy
20:41:23,285 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.oracle (missing) dependents: [service jboss.data-source.java:/OracleDS] 

20:41:23,329 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "VodaBillEAR.ear"
20:41:23,369 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "VodaBill.war"
20:41:24,051 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /VodaBill
20:41:24,054 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
20:41:24,055 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 7192ms - Started 191 of 274 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 78 services are passive or on-demand)
20:41:24,237 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "VodaBillEAR.ear"
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there was some problem with my build path - two images included in it (PNG files). Removing them fixed the error.